# Show that $\mathfrak{so}(4) \simeq \mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Show that $\mathfrak{so}(4) \simeq \mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$.

How do I proceed to show that it is true?

I know that the basis of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is the Pauli-matrices multiplied by i.
I really don't know what to do next.

Comment: Are you familiar with the isomorphism $\mathfrak{su}(2)\cong\mathfrak{so}(3)$?

Comment: Fun fact: If you interpret the parameters $a,...,f$ in the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3708404/96384 as real numbers (instead of the complex numbers used there), you are ... done.

Comment: See your question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/592932/show-that-mathfrakso4-simeq-mathfraksu2-oplus-mathfraksu2).